# Conditions on the coefficients of a Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

Could you please help me to clarify the following concepts:

1) A Fourier series $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_n e^{inx}$ is given by specifying the coefficients $a_n$ in some way. Why the condition $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |a_n|<\infty$ is necessary to be sure that the series converges to a continuous function?

2) Why $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |a_n|^2<\infty$ is a weaker condition than $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |a_n|<\infty$? (because $a_n$ are less than 1?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition 1) just ensures that the series converges.

Condition 2) is more general. For example, the sequence $a_n = {1 \over n}$ is square summable but not summable, and all summable sequences are square summable since if $|a_n| \le 1$ then $|a_n|^2 \le |a_n|$.

**Addendum**:

The above 1) doesn't actually answer what the OP asked.
The absolute summability of $a_n$ is **sufficient** for the (non
symmetric) partial sums to converge to a continuous function.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Can you explain why $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |a_n|<\infty$ is the condition for the series to converge? Does it converge to a continuous function because it converges uniformly?

Comment: $|\sum_n a_n e^{inx} | \le \sum_n |a_n|$. However, I haven't actually answered the question 1) you asked.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum_{n}|a_n| < \infty$, then $\sum_n a_n e^{inx}$ converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M-test, which means that the series $s(x)=\sum_{n}a_n e^{inx}$ is a continuous function. (However, it is not necessary for this condition to hold in order for the series to converge to a continuous function.) Because $s(x)$ is continuous, it is in $L^2[0,2\pi]$, which also gives the following Parseval identity:
$$
     \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|s(x)|^2 dx = \sum_{n}|a_n|^2 < \infty.
$$
Therefore $\sum_n |a_n| < \infty \implies \sum_n |a_n|^2 < \infty$, which proves that the second condition is weaker.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation! Have you ever considered writing a book on functional analysis? I'm sure it'll be great and clear!

Comment: @Konstantin : You're welcome, and I thank you for the compliment.